# Center footer UIImage in grouped UITableView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've centered my Image and my label in the footer of my tableView like this :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        switch section {
        case 2:
            let view     = UIView()
            let version  = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 40, tableView.frame.width, 30))
            version.font = version.font.fontWithSize(14)
            version.text = Constants.Version
            version.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
            version.textAlignment = .Center;

            let logo     = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 15, tableView.frame.width, 30))
            logo.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            logo.image   = UIImage(named: "LogoVector")

            let context  = CIContext(options: nil)
            if let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone") {
                let beginImage   = CIImage(image: logo.image!)
                currentFilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
                currentFilter.setValue(0.5, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)

                if let output = currentFilter.outputImage {
                    let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output, fromRect: output.extent)
                    let processedImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg)

                    logo.image = processedImage

                }
            }

            view.addSubview(version)
            view.addSubview(logo)

            return view
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
```

But when I'm going on the view, I have something like a freeze while the image is loading.. Do you have any idea?

regards.

Answer (score 1):

You are paused while you are doing the filtering.  Since you've hardcoded an image there, I'd suggest you add the sepia tone to the image directly with an image editor and save that.  Then you're not doing that processing at run time every time.

If that's not an option, you could just create/position the toplevel UIImageView in this method, and then do a dispatch_async() to create the image and apply the filter, and then when it's done update the image view

Comment: Thank you i'll try this solution :)